# Порядок выполнения setInterval

Tags: setinterval, javascript, циклы

Код:

```
var interval = setInterval(function () {
//Some code1
if(w > 100) {
   clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, 10)

//Some code2

var interval3 = setInterval(function () {
//Some code3
if(left2 > 1 && o2 != 1) { 
   clearInterval(interval3); 
 }
}, 10)
```

В данном случае действия выполняются в следующем порядке:

1. code1
2. code2
3. code3
4. code1
5. code2
6. code3
7. code1
8. code2
9. code3

и т.д.

А мне надо:

1. code1
2. code1
3. code1
4. code2
5. code2
6. code2
7. code3
8. code3
9. code3

Как этого добиться?

Comment: где @AlexWindHope, когда он нужен, чтобы посоветовать сначала прочитать какую-нибудь книжку по js, а потом браться за подобные задачи

Comment: @Spectre а не судьба сказать, что данный код будет выполняться асинхронно?

Comment: а не судьба признать того факта, что ТС не желает самостоятельно обратиться к тематической литературе, а продолжает искать помощи здесь, ни к чему хорошему поощерение такого повдения не привидёт

Comment: @Spectre тогда вообще зачем посылать человека очередной раз читать книгу, если он так хочет научится? Вам, видимо, по кайфу это занятие.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запускать всё в одном таймере, либо проверять какая функция сработала и разрешать/запрещать другой запускаться.

Answer (score 3):

```
for (i=0;i>3;i++){code1}
for (i=0;i>3;i++){code2}
for (i=0;i>3;i++){code3}
```